# How to loop through a list multiple times?

Tags: python

Can you loop through list (using range that has a step in it) over and over again until all the elements in the list are accessed by the loop?

I have the following lists:

```
result = []
list = ['ba', 'cb', 'dc', 'ed', 'gf', 'jh']
```

i want the outcome (result) to be:

```
result = ['dc', 'cb', 'ba', 'jh', 'gf', 'ed']
```

How do i make it loop through the first list, and appending each element to result list, starting from the third element and using 5 as a step, until all the elements are in the results list?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the algorithm you're after. You want to treat the list as circular? Starting at index 2 (the 'dc') and a step of 5 rather than 4, by the results. Do you want to not add duplicates and keep cycling around until you hit the unique ones?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you try to do; how does the result you show use a step of 4? Also, what have you tried? In the general case, using modulo indexing and item removal would let you consume any list with any step, but this is a very unusual thing to do. Without removal you need a second strategy to access all elements when the step is not relatively prime with the list length.

Comment: your example uses 5 as an increment. and it works because 5 and 6 are prime with each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the step and the length of the list are coprime, you can do:

```
result = []
list = ['ba', 'cb', 'dc', 'ed', 'gf', 'jh']
start = 2
step = 5
end = start + step*len(list)
for i in range(start, end, step):
    result.append(list[i%len(list)])
print result
```

Result:

```
['dc', 'cb', 'ba', 'jh', 'gf', 'ed']
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to loop through a list multiple times.As a more pythonic way You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) :

```
>>> from itertools import cycle,islice
>>> li= ['ba', 'cb', 'dc', 'ed', 'gf', 'jh']
>>> sl=islice(cycle(li),2,None,4)
>>> [next(sl) for _ in range(len(li))]
['dc', 'ba', 'gf', 'dc', 'ba', 'gf']
```

Note that in your expected output the step is 5 not 4.So if you use 5 as slice step you'll get your expected output :

```
>>> sl=islice(cycle(li),2,None,5)
>>> [next(sl) for _ in range(len(li))]
['dc', 'cb', 'ba', 'jh', 'gf', 'ed']
```

Comment: I must commend you on the one answer so far that does iterate through the list multitple times, as in the question's title. It still has the coprime requirement though, as the example output shows by not producing all elements.

Comment: @YannVernier There is no need to loop through a list multiple times when you can use another pythonic way.

Comment: I agree, but the question looks like an exercise in doing odd things, not efficient or obvious ones.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple solution was posted earlier, not sure why it was removed:

```
>>> a = ['ba', 'cb', 'dc', 'ed', 'gf', 'jh']
>>> result = [a[n] for n in range(2, -4, -1)]
>>> result
['dc', 'cb', 'ba', 'jh', 'gf', 'ed']
```

Comment: This only works when the list is exactly six items long (or, more generally, when the requested step is one smaller than the length of the list (in addition to the usual coprime requirement)). So it does work for the example, but it's more of a coincidence really.