# Is it possible to have unstable step in a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, range

I have a loop:

```
result = []
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
start = 2
step = 5
end = start + step*len(list)
for i in range(start, end, step):
    result.append(list[i%len(list)])
print result
```

in this case, the result would be:

```
['c', 'b', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'd']
```

But let's say, i wanted the result to be(change the starting index to 1):

```
['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e']
```

How do i make the step change after each loop, so that in the first loop the step is 5 and in the next loop it's 3 then 5 again and so on and on?

Comment: ...with another loop?

Comment: so ... You want to generate the sequence of numbers:  `3`, `8`, `11`, `16`, ...?

Comment: Put your code in a function and pass the step as a parameter?

Comment: This is a follow-on question to [how to loop through list multiple times in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32717240/4014959).

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own generator for this sort of thing:

```
from itertools import cycle
def super_range(start, stop, steps):
    csteps = cycle(steps)
    val = start
    while val < stop:
        yield val
        val += next(csteps)
```

And the usage would look something like:

```
for i in super_range(start, end, (5, 3)):
    result.append(list[i%len(list)])
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to use a separate variable to indicate the index to get from your list , and increase that index manually according to your steps. Example -

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
i = 1
new_lst = []
for j in range(len(lst)):
    new_lst.append(lst[i%len(lst)])
    if j%2 == 0:
            i += 5
    else:
            i += 3
```

Demo -

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> i = 1
>>> new_lst = []
>>> for j in range(len(lst)):
...     new_lst.append(lst[i%len(lst)])
...     if j%2 == 0:
...             i += 5
...     else:
...             i += 3
...
>>> new_lst
['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e']
```

Also, you should not use `list` as a variable name  , it shadows the built-in function `list` , which means after defining your `list` variable, you would not be able to use the built-in function `list()` .

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you want to do instead of iterating and changing the step you can use and python built-in function or `itertools` module. In this case you can sue `zip` function and `iterools.chain`:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((j,i) for i,j in zip(li[0::2],li[1::2])))
['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e']
```

In other cases you might need to use some functions like `itertools.islice()` and `zip_longest`

Answer (score 0):

Is it a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop? I.e. one when you don't know how many trips around the loop it'll take, but have a good reason to believe that something will terminate the loop. Outline code:

```
i, inc, newlst = 1, 2, []
while i < len(lst) and i >= 0:
  newlst.append( lst[i] )
  # if some_condition: inc = some_new_value
  i += inc
```

A similar structure uses `while True`  with `if something: break` inside.

generators (above) are another approach.